# How LaTeX compiler is written

Tags: compiling, latex-misc

Looking for some introductory materials on LaTeX compiler. I would like to know more about how a LaTeX compiler is built

Comment: LaTeX isn't a compiler. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6776/what-are-tex-and-latex

Comment: @Axel Sorry I am looking for `Latex Compiler` design. I didnt say LaTeX is a compiler either ;)

Comment: There's no LaTeX compiler, however. TeX has compilers.

Comment: Also review your earlier question about [tex engine and distribution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21863/tex-distribution-and-engine)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can read Knuth's *TeX: The Program*. The [PDF file](http://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/generic/knuth/tex/) from `tex.web` source is available on TeX Live distribution.

LaTeX is no more than a set of macro. See the documented source code of LaTeX2e, say, [`source2e` and `classes`](http://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/).