# Meaning of "Macro packages", "TeX engines" and "Distributions" of TeX

Tags: packages, compiling, distributions

I was wondering what relations and differences are between "Macro packages", "TeX engines" and "Distributions" of TeX？

I saw these concepts when looking at the following table at the end of [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX):
[image]

I am not able to find their meanings, and wonder what they mean?

Comment: Possible duplicates (when combined): [TeX Distribution and Engine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/21863/5764) and [The differences between TeX engines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13593/5764). *Macro packages* are just a collection of macros, packages up into a bundle.

Comment: @Werner: Thanks! (1) What do you mean by “packages up into a bundle“？ (2) Is LaTex a (Marco) package of Tex?

Comment: (1) Should have read "Packaged into a bundle". (2) Plain TeX itself contains macros, and could be considered the first level above the TeX engine. LaTeX is built on top of plain TeX. That is, LaTeX is a bunch of macros built as an additional interface between the user and plain TeX (see [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)).

Comment: @werner -- latex _doesn't_ provide an interface to plain tex, and indeed, some of the things it does are explicitly _not_ according to plain's view of the world.

Comment: @wasteofspace: depends on what you mean by "plain tex": if you mean "plain tex – the macro language", then yes, LaTeX *does* provide an interface. If you mean "plain tex – the format", then… well, LaTeX *does* use plain as a base for many things.

Comment: See http://www.tug.org/levels.html

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58431/glossary-of-tex-and-latex-terms/58449#58449 for some definitions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The list is slightly muddled, through category errors; the criterion for inclusion is obviously "there's a wikpedia page on this one".

However, https://texfaq.org/FAQ-texthings covers a bunch of them (mostly engines and format macro packages), and other early answers in http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html cover a lot of the rest.