# Texmaker-log file not found

Tags: texmaker

I encountered a problem when trying to run pdfLaTeX using Texmaker: I get

> log file not found

for the test "hello world" script.

I tried reinstalling MikTeX and Texmaker, but still get the same problem.

Anybody has any idea?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Did you restart PC to take the Path of miktex bin into effect after MiKTeX installation ?. Verify on [command line window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Command_Prompt.png) by typing `pdflatex sample2e` to get a `sample2e.pdf` document to ensure TeX distribution installed properly. BTW Are you using latest [version TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html). Save the filename as `filename.tex` with `.tex` extension

Comment: I encounter the same problem today. It worked fine a few days ago. Suddenly it did not work anymore. When I typed `pdflatex sample2e` on the command line window, it says `pdflatex is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`.

Comment: You should try to [run TeXmaker as administrator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114315/5764). Does that solve your problem?

Comment: I have this problem, and can confirm that running TeXmaker (v 3.2 on Ubuntu 12.04) as root does not fix it.  Several "log file not found" dialogs pop up, and then the PDF is successfully generated.  What causes them?

Comment: Did you installed TeX distribution correctly? TeXmaker is just a plain text editor, and it will not work without TeX distribution.

Comment: @texenthusiast Your hint worked for me. Miktex was not in my %PATH% anymore. Stupid Windows has this stupid arbitrary max length for %PATH%. The max length is a major cause of PAIN when trying yo get programs like miktex to run because it won't be able to add itself to the path, and then editors won't work. If you have this problem, make sure to restart your editor after making the changes!

Comment: @Domi if you are interested switch to [TeXLive distro](http://www.tug.org/texlive/) and use [install-tl.zip](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and continue the installation as per http://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/install_texlive_windows.html

Comment: @texenthusiast reason? :)

Comment: @Domi See more at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20036/what-are-the-advantages-of-tex-live-over-miktex/20045#20045

Answer (score 10):

I have "log file not found" errors, but the PDF is successfully generated.

This appears to be caused by the **-output-directory=/tmp** option in my configuration for the latex executable.  Texmaker looks for the logfile in the same directory as your source file.

I was able to solve this by creating an empty file in the same directory as my .tex file.

For example, if your file is called `myfile.tex`, create an empty file in that same directory called `myfile.log`.  It suppresses the error.

You can also `ln -s /tmp/myfile.log ./` in your project directory, which suppresses the error *and* shows you the error log <s>if you make</s> when you make errors.

I am using Texmaker v3.2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Have a look at solutions to common problems based on TeXmaker errors [Unable to compile TeXmaker 4.0.2 with MiKTeX 2.9](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113680/15717)

Comment: Thanks @texenthusiast but these don't apply to me.  I'm not on Windows, and my latex installation does indeed work -- my PDFs were successfully generated (I just had to click through some annoying messageboxes).  I've updated my answer with this info.

Comment: BTW Just for info: Latest version of TeXmaker is [4.0.3](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html)

Comment: Are you using that on Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded from here http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#linux. [Those errors from TeXmaker](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113680/15717) are relevant for any OS and some are specific to OS also. It's a mix.

Comment: My solution is to clean additional files generated by the editor and restart the application!

Answer (score 9):

> Texmaker -> Options/Configure Texmaker/Commands/LaTeX...

click on the folder icon and find this file:

```
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/latex.exe
```

> Texmaker -> Options/Configure Texmaker/Commands/PdfLaTeX...

find

```
C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe
```

Comment: You're a hero to me

Comment: As a newbie to LaTeX, I had just installed Texmaker on Windows 10 and not MikTeX. Installing MikTeX solved the `log file not found`

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem in one hour by uninstalling MikTex and Texmaker and reinstalling it again ...
(after many hours struggling to solve the problem...)

Answer (score 1):

I already posted this in the comments, but it seems to be a common problem. As @texenthusiast mentions, you want to make sure that you can use `pdflatex` (or whatever LaTeX compiler you want to use) from command line. The following is for **Windows**:

First, test it out. Press `Windows-Key`+`R` (for *Run*). Then, type `cmd` to open Windows' command line terminal. Now type `pdflatex`. If you, like some people in the comments, encounter *command not found*, below is a way to fix this. If this is not your problem, the following won't help you (press `CTRL`+`C` to exit the program).

1. Make sure, you have MiKTex  (or some other TeX or LaTeX distribution) installed.
2. Make sure that it's binary folder is added to the Windows PATH. To do that, [follow these instructions](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) on how to edit your PATH system variable. It is a semicolon-separated list of folders from where it will look-up any executable file that you try to use (such as pdflatex). Add your MiKTex bin folder to it. For me, that is: `c:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\`.
3. The PATH variable (for some retarded reason) has a max length of 1000 characters or so. If you, like me, tend to exceed that limit, you might want to take a look at [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405091/how-avoid-over-populate-path-environment-variable-in-windows) on the matter.
4. Always restart your editor (or command line terminal) after changing system variables (they get loaded when a program starts).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I was using LaTeX on ubuntu initially. It was running nicely but after installation of Mint I found this error and solved by installing TeX Live for linux platform from www.tug.org/texlive. TeX Live works as platform for TeXMaker.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but it was solved like this:

In Options->Commands, I didn't use the complete paths, just the names of the commands for latex, pdflatex and xelatex.

I.e. I typed `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and not `C:\MikTex\miktex\bin\latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

Before trying this, open command prompt and make sure these commands exist.

I am using Windows XP in an old machine (2007), but the latest versions of MiKTEX and texmaker.

I don't know if this works for you, but you could try...

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem in latex version of Texmaker by putting a ".tex" extension on the filename, which texmaker doesn't seem to do automatically with "Save As."

So I had "document.v2" as a filename and it gave me this same error, but "document.v2.tex" resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error on Ubuntu 14.04 with TexMaker 4.1 by going to `Options -> Settings File -> Reset Settings`.

I figured there was a configuration file somewhere that was still linking to the old path after I deleted all the files except the `.tex` file in my project folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was a double space in the name of the tex file. Replacing it with single space solved the problem completely.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, there seems to be an issue when the path variable contains a space character.

The defaults in `Options` -> `Configure TexMaker` -> `Commands` were:

- `latex -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` and
- `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

This should work because both binaries (latex and pdflatex) are in the PATH environment variable (`pdflatex` can be run from `cmd` without the full path). However, and this is my best guess, it seems that Texmaker does not escape the paths properly and having a space in the path does not work. To work around this, you should provide the full commands in the settings, escaping them properly:

- `"C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\latex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`
- `"C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex`

These paths might differ for you, but at the very least, `YOUR_USERNAME` must be replaced of course. The main thing is that there is a space, namely in the `MiKTeX 2.9` part, making it necessary that there are quotes (`"`) around the path to the binary.

On top of this, we created the `.log` file manually in the folder. I am not sure if this is necessary after fixing the aforementioned configuration issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was due to the fact that I checked "use build directory" box. This directory did not exist. When I unchecked the box, it all went fine.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you add some detailed informations? See [How do I write a good answer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and I was able to get it to work as follows. Go to the following menu:

```
texmaker -> Preferences
```

In the commands window I unchecked... 'Use a "build" subdirectory for output files". Things started to work after that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Options -> Manage Setting File -> Rest Settings]

I use Mac and got the same issue in TexMaker "Log File not Found". It was solved by just clicking "Reset Settings"