# Anything like TexPad OSX for Windows?

Tags: windows, editors

My friend needs a proper TeX editor for Windows and I think TeXPad OSx is by far the best. Is there anything like this for Windows 7?

Comment: I would encourage your friend to look at the editors listed in the above question.  Everybody has their own favorite editor (mine happened to be emacs with AUCTeX and then the infernal program took over the rest of my life); don't impose yours as an only option :)  That said, TeXmaker is similar in style and function.

Comment: @SeanAllred We looked together and we could not get hang of them such as TexMaker (getting odd bugs, asked there in the comment for clarification). I am not recommending any shxt to my friends. I suggested him to use Mathematica as his "editor" instead until he found a proper editor -- having a bad LaTex editor can waste a massive amount of expensive production time! Mathematica typesetting is pretty nice and you have just drag-drop-images and ESC latex ESC works nicely :D

Comment: Mathematica isn't so much as a LaTeX editor as it is a mathematics editor and computation engine which happens to have LaTeX export options :) Out of curiosity, what kind of bugs are you getting?

Comment: @SeanAllred "no log file found" in typesetting with pdflatex.

Comment: How very strange.  Have you tried http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117631/texmaker-log-file-not-found?

Comment: @SeanAllred no, we haven't. We decided that my friend is looking for a proper editor and writing things by hand. We don't have time to this kind of half-finished products...heavy deadlines...

Answer (score 1):

I think TeXworks http://www.tug.org/texworks/ would do the job.

Comment: -1? for the answer? Thanks for that one, it prevents me of reading questions and answering them next time...

Answer (score 1):

What about [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/about/about-texniccenter/)?

It may not quite be quite as neat as TexPad, but then it's also free and open source.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very arrogant idea: **Use Mathematica**. Just ESC LaTex ESC and you can do all calculations also with it. When you get hang of basic LaTex commands and find the best editor on the market, use it but for homeworks -- Mathematica should be totally fine!

**Example about how I work with my assignments, very cool!**

[image]

Comment: Except for, you know, the exorbitant pricetag. :P Even the student edition is upwards of 100 USD.  I can't say I didn't do this for my own homeworks once upon a time, but it turned out to be extremely inefficient.

Comment: @SeanAllred I paid 64 pounds for the student edition (googling Mathematica discount coupon gets you 15% off). And if you want to go the evil way, you can use Torrents to get it free (with some malware possibly). And you can use Mathematica in some universities for free. There are always options to use Mathematica, you just have to be creative! ~100USD is still a very little in comparison to the business price in the range of many thousands USD :D