# Problem compiling: Log file not found

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I downloaded MiKTeX and the Texmaker editor. After writing and saving my script, when I try to compile using `pdflatex` it gives me a "log file not found" error message. What's wrong or how do I fix this?

Comment: What happens if you compile from the command line?

Comment: before that did you get an error that pdflatex could not be run?

Comment: thank you all. Hi, @Bernard. I compiled from Toolbar. Today i try to compile another simple file and I don't have problem. Probably there is an error in the code but I don't understand.

Comment: Hi @DavidCarlisle. When I compile this file nothing appears on my desk but there is no file log.

Comment: Compile from the command line, you will see messages from the compiler.

Comment: the usual reason for getting no log is that latex did not run, either because it isn't installed or isn't on the path or the editor is looking in the wrong place, but in any of those cases you should get am error from the operating system that the command was not found.

Comment: The most common reason for Texmaker first time failure is a missing MiKTeX or its path (see the answer by Domi in the link below.) However if it has worked on some occasion it suggests a secondary issue about filepath or filenames If thats the case there are other answers in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117631/texmaker-log-file-not-found **AVOID** *the popular "shinybasics" or "Luc" answers they later cause issues* YOU CAN as the question says add the path to MiKTeX\bin in the "Add to PATH" section of configure commands (bottom Left) & as per "Stergios" remove them from each command

Comment: Unless they have changed it in the last week, the version of MikTeX downloaded has bugs involving the use of `/bin/` instead of `\bin\ ` in path names.  This can be fixed (as of Dec 30) by updating the packages.