# winedt texify problem "--interaction=errorstopmode: unknown option"

Tags: winedt

After installing CTeX on my G partition. I found that I could not get winedt to compile LaTeX normally. Later I realize that is because winedt didn't detect the MiKTeX installed on G partition. So I manually changed all the path to the proper path. And now I can use "L" button and "dvipdf" button to generate pdf file properly.

**But I found that I can't use "Texify" or "PdfTexify" button, it will give error message "texify: --interaction=errorstopmode: unknown option". I want to know what is wrong with my configuration?**

Comment: WinEdt is not seen MiKTeX, otherwise it should work. Check it in Options -> Execution Modes -> Diagnosis.

Comment: I change the path. First "Latex" then "dvipdf" already works. But "PdfTexify" didn't work.

Comment: where did you change the path?

Comment: in the execution mode. "Tex system" tab. and also in the "console application" tab, "Accessories"

Comment: Corresponding to TeXify, do you have a question mark?

Comment: sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. A question mark?

Comment: Yes, like the one you can see for ConTeXt in this answer of mine http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121504/27635

Comment: No, there is no question mark

Comment: @karlkoeller I uninstalled winedt7.0 and reinstall winedt8.0, then change the path. Now everything is working properly.