# What is the difference beween all the paths from tex to pdf file? Which one is better?

Tags: pdftex, ps2pdf, dvipdf

There are several ways to get from a TeX source file to a PDF file using LaTeX:

- LaTeX to `dvi` to `pdf` (via `dvipdf` or `dvipdfm` or `dvipdfmx`).
- LaTeX to `dvi` to `ps` to `pdf` (via `DviPs` followed by `ps2pdf`).
- pdfLaTeX.

Is there an advantage to using any of the first two over the third?

Comment: > does the fact MikTeX use XeLaTeX to crete all of these make any difference?

MikTeX ships XeLaTeX, but pdfLaTeX is just pdftex with the pdflatex format, versus XeLaTeX, which is xetex with the xelatex format. I've never heard of a way to use XeLaTeX with pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Right now the first part is only going to get opinions ('better' in what way?), while the latter is based on a false premise (MiKTeX does not do that - I've never used it, but I'm sure it doesn't do that). Also, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21863/tex-distribution-and-engine but there is probably a better duplicate somewhere.

Comment: Historically, dvi->ps->pdf was the first available (back when PDF stood for Proprietary Document Format).

Comment: As far as I know, `dvipdf` should be regarded as obsolete and `dvipdfm` is not existing any more, being superseded by `dvipdfmx`.

Comment: @cfr, PTNobel: I have modified my question to make it more precise.  MikTeX uses the XeTeX engine, not XeLaTeX.  And I have tried to make the question less opinion oriented.

Comment: No, miktex does not *use* the XeTeX engine. It provides all major engines: pdftex, luatex and xetex.

Comment: And in our times, if the result should be a pdf-file, use an engine that produces it directly.

Comment: @ltcomdata MiKTeX does *not* use the XeTeX engine. It *provides* this engine, among others. XeLaTeX is XeTeX with LaTeX format - it doesn't use a different engine. But you also have pdfTeX, LuaTeX, TeX, ConTeXt.... *You* may wish to use XeTeX, but that's a different issue. I don't see how this question can possibly be answered except by pointing out that it is based on false assumptions.

Comment: @cfr, MaxNoe, PTNobel: well, I was under the miss-conception that everything in MiKTeX was somehow handled by the XeLaTeX in some kind of compatibility mode.  I apologize for being wrong about that.  I have deleted the part of the question having to do with XeTeX.  The first part of the question is still valid, though.